# Alternative Touch Events for Mouse drag function?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I was just having trouble adding the touch event listeners to this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const slider = document.querySelector('.home-cates-row');
    let isDown = false;
    let startX;
    let scrollLeft;
    
    slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
      isDown = true;
      slider.classList.add('active');
      startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
      scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      isDown = false;
      slider.classList.remove('active');
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      isDown = false;
      slider.classList.remove('active');
    });
    slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      if(!isDown) return;
      e.preventDefault();
      const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
      const walk = (x - startX) * 1;
      slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
      console.log(walk);
    });
});
```

This is working fine for the mouse but not for touch devices.

What is the best practice for this touch compatibility?
Do I have to use JQuery Mobile?
Or do I make a new function with 'touch' event listeners?

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pointer events, which extend the MouseEvent interface to include touch and stylus support (and others). Try replacing `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mouseleave`, and `mousemove` with `pointerdown`, `pointerup`, `pointerleave`, and `pointermove`. You can read about pointer events [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events). See [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer%20events) for browser coverage.

Comment: @HamzaAfzal If this solution worked for you, could you please check it as the answer?